# What is wrong with this TextReader?

Tags: c#, io, filestream

I am using this piece of code to read from file but have an error "Cannot create an instance of abstract class or interface  "System.IO.TextReader""

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
       using(TextReader reader = new TextReader(fileStream))//error
       {
           ...       
       }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot instantiate TextReader object directly, its an abstract class. Try using StreamReader or StringReader instead.

```
using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{

}
```

See details/usage of StreamReader on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

`TextReader` is an abstract class so you have to use `StreamReader`- a subclass of TextReader.

Answer (score 1):

Use it like:

```
using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(fileName){
    string line = reader.ReadLine();

}
```

Should work  for you.